# Нагрузка на сервер Node и Ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js, веб-программирование

Я создаю чат в реальном времени. Чтобы компенсировать нагрузку на сервер, решил использовать node.js, вместо ajax. Но мне после каждого отправленного сообщения в чат, нужно сохранять его в бд, опять же используя ajax. Т.е. нагрузка на сервер не упадет, ведь каждую секунду или несколько секунд, придется делать ajax запрос, чтобы сохранить переписку или есть другой способ сохранить все с незначительной нагрузкой на сервер?

Comment: Зачем такая необходимость сохранять каждую секунду? Храни в массиве на сервере. И по таймеру там....раз в минуту сохраняй в бд, очищая массив...частично

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример решения задачи подобной вашей с использованием redis и websocket https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/wa-bluemix-html5chat/ Думаю, что приведенное решение смело можно брать за основу. Вот разве что вместо socket.io я бы посоветовал primus. Кстати говоря, redis для снижения нагрузки можно запускать на отдельном сервере.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.